# Change background div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, button, background-color

I want to change the backColor of my div on a button click using Jquery.
Currently i am doing this by changing my class.

Here is my Css:

```
.GreenColor
{

background-color:#00FF00;
}

.RedColor
{

background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Here is my Script in my php file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){


$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("RedColor").toggleClass("GreenColor");
});
});
</script>
```

But somehow it does nothing.

Could use some help here ;)

Comment: please add your relevant html code

Comment: How do you define the button? Show that HTML too, please

Comment: Your probably missed a "." or a "#" symbol before the "button".

Comment: Please share your `HTML` structure

Comment: in spite of answers pouring in, your question remains sort of pointless without the html.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ to get started reading the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try like

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("RedColor GreenColor");
});
```

Or even try like

```
$("#button").toggle(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").removeClass("RedColor").addClass("GreenColor");
}, function() {
    $(this).closest("div").removeClass("GreenColor").addClass("RedColor");
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting html.

Comment: I did but timer makes me unable to accept within 10 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Use ***.toggleClass()*** uses the second parameter for determining
>   whether the class should be added or removed. If this parameter's
>   value is true, then the class is added; if false, the class is
>   removed. In essence, the statement:

```
$("button").click(function() {
      $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("RedColor GreenColor");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Documentations says

You should use `$(':button')` selector because:

> :button is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification,
>   queries using :button cannot take advantage of the performance boost
>   provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the
>   best performance when using :button to select elements, first select
>   the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":button").

see fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/kE3W8/